# How to remove a string between a pattern using sed / awk command in linux

Tags: sed, awk

How can I remove the letter `f` from the below mentioned string in a file:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m
```

This needs to be done **only** by  using  delimiter `;` using sed or awk.

The output will be:

```
a;b;c;d;e;g;h;i;j;k;l;m
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Wouldn't awk be easier?

Comment: `s/f//` -- or am I missing something?

Comment: @devnull: That would leave an extra semicolon :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'this needs to be done only by using delimiter ;'?

Comment: If I need to display the unwanted data I would use something similar to: cat 123data.log | awk -F ';' '{print $5}'

Comment: Do you like to remove `f` or the sixth field?

Comment: @Jotne the sixth field

Comment: Then this should do: `awk -F\; '{$6="";sub(/;;/,";")}1' OFS=\;`

Comment: @Jotne : Its looks right, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^;];//6' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m' | sed 's/;*f;*/;/'
a;b;c;d;e;g;h;i;j;k;l;m
```

Answer (score 0):

easier using perl pie than sed (unless sed has added an inplace-edit flag in the last 20 years).

```
perl -p -i -e  's/;f;/;/' fileName.txt
```

Comment: How do you know that `e` comes before `f`?

Comment: @LutzHorn - author wasn't clear if this was a general case or a specific case.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/f;//' YourFile
```

be carefull if f is only a sample pattern for the sample due to possible special character in a généric pattern